# SQL : Finding duration between 2 events using LEAD/LAG and/or ROW_NUMBER over a partition

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with a series of events by vehicle and time.
The vehicle is either connected or disconnected trough time.

I'm interrested in computing the duration between a connected event (connected = 1) and the following disconnect event (connected = 0)

I would like to use SQL's [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) over a partition.
I'm wondering how to partition my data to achieve this goal.

Of course VehicleId is the first candidate. What would be the second computed field?

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Events (VehicleId int, connected bit, Time DateTime);

INSERT INTO #Events (VehicleId, connected, Time)
VALUES(25931, 0, '2020-10-13 16:02:10.117'),
(25931, 1, '2020-10-13 11:32:39.213'),
(25931, 1, '2020-10-13 10:04:29.470'),
(25925, 1, '2020-10-13 07:41:31.637'),
(25925, 1, '2020-10-13 06:06:22.600'),
(25931, 1, '2020-10-13 05:23:19.433'),
(25927, 1, '2020-10-13 01:01:36.460'),
(25931, 0, '2020-10-13 17:55:10.380'),
(25931, 0, '2020-10-13 12:14:10.837'),
(25931, 0, '2020-10-13 10:53:54.527'),
(25925, 0, '2020-10-13 09:06:52.063'),
(25931, 0, '2020-10-13 08:32:45.230'),
(25925, 0, '2020-10-13 06:42:37.627'),
(25925, 0, '2020-10-13 05:12:08.070'),
(25927, 0, '2020-10-13 04:42:23.887'),
(25927, 0, '2020-10-13 00:56:36.090')

SELECT * FROM #Events ORDER BY Time ASC

DROP TABLE #Events
```

SELECT query result:

```
VehicleId   connected   Time
25927   0   2020-10-13 00:56:36.090
25927   1   2020-10-13 01:01:36.460
25927   0   2020-10-13 04:42:23.887
25925   0   2020-10-13 05:12:08.070
25931   1   2020-10-13 05:23:19.433
25925   1   2020-10-13 06:06:22.600
25925   0   2020-10-13 06:42:37.627
25925   1   2020-10-13 07:41:31.637
25931   0   2020-10-13 08:32:45.230
25925   0   2020-10-13 09:06:52.063
25931   1   2020-10-13 10:04:29.470
25931   0   2020-10-13 10:53:54.527
25931   1   2020-10-13 11:32:39.213
25931   0   2020-10-13 12:14:10.837
25931   0   2020-10-13 16:02:10.117
25931   0   2020-10-13 17:55:10.380
```

EDIT:
The result set I'm expecting is something like

```
VehicleId, Duration (min)
25927, 221
```

for the following two events:

```
25927   1   2020-10-13 01:01:36.460
25927   0   2020-10-13 04:42:23.887
```

And so on for each vehicleid and a pair of connected/disconnected.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 2: According to comments FIRST_VALUE/LAST_VALUE are not a good fit. Question updated.

Comment: What have you tried so far with those functions, and why didn't they give the results you were after?

Comment: Please show us the results that you want

Comment: Also, is this not a gaps and island question? If so, `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` aren't the right functions. There are plenty of examples of gaps and island problems on SO, and they make use of `LEAD`/`LAG` and/or `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @Larnu I'm afraid it is. But I still can't see how to partition here.

Comment: What relation does ID `25931` have to ID `25927`?

Comment: @Larnu There is none.

Comment: Then I don't udnerstand your expected results. You say that the the resulting duration is 221 for vehicle ID is `25931`, which is based on 2 events for vehicle `25927`. If they don't relate why does the values from vehicle `25927` give a result for ``25931``?

Comment: @Larnu Sorry it is a copy/paste error.

Comment: Will a row where `connected` have a value of `1` **always** be followed by a `0` for that vehicle? Could there be successive `1`s?

Comment: @OlivierMATROT: please show us the results you want for the entire dataset. As it stands, there is more than one way to understand your question...

Comment: @Larnu In theory yes,but in practice I should ignore rows when it is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks* like you want to sum the time difference on "transition" rows, where a vehicle goes from status disconnected to connected. If so, you can use `lag()`:

```
select vehicleid, sum(datediff(minute, lag_time, time)) sum_diff
from (
    select e.*, 
        lag(connected) over(partition by vehicleid order by time) lag_connected,
        lag(time)      over(partition by vehicleid order by time) lag_time
    from #events e
) e
where connected = 0 and lag_connected = 1
group by vehicleid
```

For your sample data, **[this returns](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9f575bbdad9f27968cdc9090c10df56)**:

```
vehicleid | sum_diff
--------: | -------:
    25925 |      121
    25927 |      221
    25931 |      280
```

Comment: @OlivierMATROT: yes. Larnu's and my answer are quite similar, which just one difference, that my query does not assumes that a `1` is always followed by a `0`.

Comment: That would make it more robust because I'm not 100% sure that the dataset I will work on will have 1 always followed by 0. Let's wait a few days for me to choose the accepted answer.

Comment: But instead, it ignores the first `1`, @GMB, so has a different assumption. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db2c766abd5916fd64c2456d833e4840)

Comment: @Larnu: I think both our answers have this assumption in common, basically. I am not criticizing, by the way! Just pinpoiting. The question is not deterministic about a given solution, as a I commented earlier.

Comment: I know, just pointing out that we have similar, but different, assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that a `1` is **always** followed by a `0` for that vehicle, then you can use `LEAD` to get the next time, and then `SUM` the `DATEDIFF`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT VehicleId,
           connected,
           [Time], --Time is a data type, and doesn't have a date portion, I would suggest using a different name
           LEAD(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY [Time]) AS NextTime
    FROM #Events E
    WHERE VehicleID = 25927)
SELECT VehicleID,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[Time],NextTime)) AS Duration
FROM CTE
WHERE Connected = 1
GROUP BY VehicleId;
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not use FIRST_VALUE/LAST_VALUE.

```
;
WITH Ranked AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        DateRowNumber = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Time)
    FROM  #Events            
)
,Joined AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        JoiningId = CASE WHEN connected=1 THEN LEAD(DateRowNumber) OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleId ORDER BY Time) ELSE NULL END  
    FROM Ranked 
)
SELECT 
    J.VehicleId, 
    J.Time, 
    R.Time, 
    DifferencetInSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND,J.Time, R.Time) 
FROM 
    Joined J
    INNER JOIN Ranked R ON r.DateRowNumber = J.JoiningId
ORDER BY 
    J.VehicleId, J.Time

    SELECT * FROM #Events ORDER BY VehicleID, Time


VehicleId   Time                    Time                    DifferencetInSeconds
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --------------------
25925       2020-10-13 06:06:22.600 2020-10-13 06:42:37.627 2175
25925       2020-10-13 07:41:31.637 2020-10-13 09:06:52.063 5121
25927       2020-10-13 01:01:36.460 2020-10-13 04:42:23.887 13247
25931       2020-10-13 05:23:19.433 2020-10-13 08:32:45.230 11366
25931       2020-10-13 10:04:29.470 2020-10-13 10:53:54.527 2965
25931       2020-10-13 11:32:39.213 2020-10-13 12:14:10.837 2491
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'GV or LV' ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant FV and LV -> FIRST_VALUE/LAST_VALUE